# There is already an object named 'DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK' in the database

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, liquibase

I have a problem with liquibase, the application is spring boot, ms sql server

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: There is already an object named 'DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK' in the database. [Failed SQL: (2714) CREATE TABLE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID int NOT NULL, LOCKED bit NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED datetime2(3), LOCKEDBY nvarchar(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID))]
```

Comment: you want to create DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK table, but it is already exists in the database.

Comment: i know but why this create  DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK

Comment: you should provide more information, how do you config your app etc.

Comment: DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK is a necessary table to liquibase

Comment: Have you tried [reading the documentation](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/databasechangeloglock-table.html)?

Answer (score 1):

problem solved, I added too many permissions on sql server user

Answer (score 0):

You can change the names of `databasechangelog` and `databasechangeloglock` tables by using these properties:

```
spring.liquibase.database-change-log-lock-table=YOUR_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
spring.liquibase.database-change-log-table=YOUR_DATABASECHANGELOG
```